# Multi-page window cannot highlight Entry text with callback

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

Recently I've changed the layout of my program to include a multi-page window similar to what is in the provided example.

In the original, two-window configuration I had a binding set on each window to highlight all of the text in the `Entry` widget, based on a condition (no condition present in the example). This was fine.

Upon upgrading to a multi-page window, I tried to combine the callback to highlight text by passing the relevant widget and calling `widget.select_range(0, END)` as it is done in the example. Now I can't seem to highlight any text on mouse-click.

In addition to this, I've also tested my example code with having a separate callback for each `Entry`; even this would not highlight the text in the `Entry` upon clicking on it.

Could this have something to do with `lift`ing frames & where the focus lies? As a test I've added a similar callback for "submitting" the `Entry` value, and this is working fine. At this point I'm confused as to why this wouldn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I forgot that to solve the highlighting problem, I've needed to include a `return "break"` line in the callback that is used to highlight the text.

Now, with this included, I have some very strange behavior with the `Entry` widgets. I can't click on them unless they have been focused using the `tab` key.

Is there any way to work around this problem?

Here is the example code I have been playing with (with the updated return statement):

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window():

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.s1 = StringVar()
        self.s1.set("")
        self.s2 = StringVar()
        self.s2.set("")

        # Frame 1

        self.f1 = Frame(root, width = 50, height = 25)
        self.f1.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 2)

        self.page1 = Label(self.f1, text = "This is the first page's entry: ")
        self.page1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = W)
        self.page1.grid_columnconfigure(index = 0, minsize = 90)

        self.val1 = Label(self.f1, text = self.s1.get(), textvariable = self.s1)
        self.val1.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = E)

        self.l1 = Label(self.f1, text = "Frame 1 Label")
        self.l1.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = W)

        self.e1 = Entry(self.f1, width = 25)
        self.e1.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = E)
        self.e1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.event(self.e1))
        self.e1.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.submit(self.e1, self.s1))

        # Frame 2

        self.f2 = Frame(root, width = 50, height = 25)
        self.f2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 2)

        self.page2 = Label(self.f2, text = "This is the 2nd page's entry: ")
        self.page2.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = W)
        self.page2.grid_columnconfigure(index = 0, minsize = 90)

        self.val2 = Label(self.f2, text = self.s2.get(), textvariable = self.s2)
        self.val2.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = E)

        self.l2 = Label(self.f2, text = "Frame 2 Label")
        self.l2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = W)

        self.e2 = Entry(self.f2, width = 25)
        self.e2.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = E)
        self.e2.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.event(self.e2))
        self.e2.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.submit(self.e2, self.s2))

        self.b1 = Button(root, width = 15, text = "Page 1", command = lambda: self.page(1), relief = SUNKEN)
        self.b1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = E)

        # Buttons

        self.b2 = Button(root, width = 15, text = "Page 2", command = lambda: self.page(2))
        self.b2.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = W)

        # Start with Frame 1 lifted

        self.f1.lift()

    def page(self, val):
        self.b1.config(relief = RAISED)
        self.b2.config(relief = RAISED)

        if val == 1:
            self.f1.lift()
            self.b1.config(relief = SUNKEN)
        else:
            self.f2.lift()
            self.b2.config(relief = SUNKEN)

    def event(self, widget): 
        widget.select_range(0, END)
        return "break"

    def submit(self, widget, target):
        target.set(widget.get())

root = Tk()
w = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this has been a productive question. If anyone in the future is doing something similar to this and needs a reference for how to solve the problem:

I was able to work around the problem by forcing the `Entry` widgets into focus every time I switch frames, and using the `return "break"` statement that I mention in the question's update.

This isn't *ideal*, as every time a page is changed you automatically focus on the `Entry` widget, but once the widget is in focus it's behavior is exactly what I would expect so this isn't of great concern. In my program, if you are changing pages it is quite likely you will use the `Entry` widget anyway (it is a search entry).

Here's the final changes required to make the code work correctly:

```
# .... some code ....

    self.f1.lift()
    self.e1.focus_force()

def page(self, val):
    self.b1.config(relief = RAISED)
    self.b2.config(relief = RAISED)

    if val == 1:
        self.f1.lift()
        self.b1.config(relief = SUNKEN)
        self.e1.focus_force()
    else:
        self.f2.lift()
        self.b2.config(relief = SUNKEN)
        self.e2.focus_force()

def event(self, widget): 
    widget.select_range(0, END)
    return "break"

# .... more code ....
```